# Namespace scope in SOAP / XML

Tags: xml, soap

Is this valid SOAP / XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateRoute xmlns="urn:Routs">
            <aRoute>
                <name>ToTheTop</name>
                <grade xsi:type="FrencGrade">
                    <gradeNumber>7</gradeNumber>
                    <gradeModifier>a</gradeModifier>
                </grade>
            </aRoute>
        </CreateRoute>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And if it is: in what namespace does FrenchGrade belong?  Is it in the urn:Routs namespace?

Comment: Was this attached to a service that provided a WSDL? The WSDL should have told you what namespace that element was in (also, the others wouldn't have that type in the first place, but still). ~ Also @Kim, would you mark your answer as accepted below if it was?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's correct. By doing:

```
<CreateRoute xmlns="urn:Routs">
```

...you're changing the default namespace to `urn:Routs`. This means that all unprefixed child elements will exist in this new namespace.

Unless of course:

- you explicitly add new elements using a different prefix
- you create a new child element and *change its default namespace*, in which case its children will be in that new namespace